# moment.js - UTC does not work as i expect it

Tags: javascript, node.js, utc, momentjs

testing in the node console:

```
var moment = require('moment');

// create a new Date-Object
var now = new Date(2013, 02, 28, 11, 11, 11);

// create the native timestamp
var native = Date.UTC(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds());

// create the timestamp with moment
var withMoment = moment.utc(now).valueOf()
// it doesnt matter if i use moment(now).utc().valueOf() or moment().utc(now).valueOf()

// native: 1364469071000
// withMoment: 1364465471000
native === withMoment // false!?!?! 

// this returns true!!!
withMoment === now.getTime()
```

why isnt native the same timestamp as withMoment? why does withMoment return the timestamp calculated from the current local-time? how can i achieve that moment.utc() returns the same as Date.UTC()?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call `moment.utc()` the same way you're calling `Date.UTC`:

```
var withMoment = moment.utc([now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds()]).valueOf();
```

I think calling `moment.utc(now)` will make it assume `now` lives in the local timezone, and it will convert it to UTC first, hence the difference.

Comment: already tried that, and saw that it works. is this the only option i have? thought moment.js saves me code and time ;-(

Comment: You can pass `native` to `moment.utc()` instead of `now`, that'll work too.

Comment: yeah, still not what i wanted, but ty ;-)

Comment: Man, you saved my day. Please have a beer and send me the bill.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is essentially this.

```
var now    = new Date(2013, 02, 28, 11, 11, 11);
var native = Date.UTC(2013, 02, 28, 11, 11, 11);

console.log(now === utc); // false
console.log(now - utc); // your offset from GMT in milliseconds
```

Because `now` is constructed in the current timezone and `native` is constructed in UTC, they will differ by your offset. 11 AM PST != 11 AM GMT.