# Moment JS - parse UTC and convert to Local and vice versa

Tags: momentjs

I have gone through the documentation and am a tiny bit confused about how to proceed.
There are similar questions, but none talk about parsing particular dates received in formats and swapping between local and utc dates.

1. I receive a local datetime, local datetime format and need to generate utc datetime from it in a particular format and this is how I think I should do it. `moment(dateTime,localDateTimeFormat).utc().format(specifiedFormat);`
2. I receive utc datetime in a particular format and have to generate locale specific datetime in a particular format. How do i do it?
   `moment.utc(utcDateTime, utcDateTimeFormat).toDate();` gives me javascript date i believe. How do I format it then?? Do I have to create a new moment using the generated Date object?

Another thing I could do would be getting the timezone and then formatting. I wonder if I am taking the wrong route here. Please help.

Comment: Take a look at other SO posts including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133326/moment-js-utc-does-not-work-as-i-expect-it

Comment: I did go around SO but couldn't find precise answers about parsing utc dates. Getting utc of this moment was okay, but parsing and converting back to local is what got me. Thanks anyways.

Comment: This question should not be marked as duplicate.  The other question may be similar, but is distinct from this because it involves passing individual date parts, not parsing from a string with a format.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

- On Item 1 - Yes, that's one way to do it.  However, if the output format is just going to be an ISO8601 UTC timestamp, then you can call `toISOString` directly on the original moment.  Since UTC is implied by the output, it would be redundant to call `utc()` again.
- On Item 2 - Just like the `utc()` function, there's also a `local()` function.  Once you have a `moment` object, you can use `toDate` or `format` or any other of the functions described in the documentation.  No, you do not need to create a new moment using the generated date object.

  ```
  moment.utc(utcDateTime, utcDateTimeFormat).local().format(specifiedFormat)
  ```

  Again, there's more than one way to do things here.  If the `utcDateTime` is already in ISO8601 format, and contains either a `Z` or an offset like `-01:00`, then that will be taken into account and you can simply do this:

  ```
  moment(utcDateTime).format(specifiedFormat)
  ```
- On the last item you mentioned about time zones, it's difficult to tell what you are asking.  You should elaborate with specific details *in a new question*.

Comment: Yes, that local() method is what I think I can use and then tweak around things. Thanks.

Comment: utcDateTimeFormat?

Comment: @kuhaku - was from the OP.  Specifically, the format string in the second parameter should match the data provided in the first parameter.