# How to convert ISO date/time to local date/time with moment.js? Receiving odd output

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm using moment.js to convert from an ISO date/time/zone string to a local one. Based on the docs and other similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782732/moment-js-parse-utc-and-convert-to-local-and-vice-versa), what should be pretty straightforward is turning out not to be, and is giving me some odd output. Here is what I have:

```
console.log('date/time before is: ', date);
// date/time before is:  2016-12-23T23:10:00.000Z

var datetime = moment(date).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");

console.log('date/time after is: ', datetime);
// date/time after is:  pátek, prosinec 23. 2016, 3:10:00 pm
```

The format string I am using is directly from the docs. The intent is to be able to format it in the way I need it once I get it working.

Comment: its local date in czech locale. prosinec is December
 and pátek is Friday

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are using moment-with-locales, because "pátek, prosinec" is Czech for "Friday, December".

I used the following cdn link for moment.js:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js

And this code:

```
var date = new Date().toISOString();

console.log(date);

var datetime = moment(date).format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");

console.log(datetime);
```

And got the expected result. Here's a [fiddle using moment.js](https://jsfiddle.net/kaqypL8o/) that produces the output I think you want.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I was using locale/cs when creating the date. Ty.

Comment: Np, glad you found the issue.