# Moment js UTC+00:00 giving 1 hr extra

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment js for date formatting based on time zone. I have following example

```js
console.log(moment("11-Apr-2017 13:00 UTC+00:00", "D-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:Z").format('x'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

It is giving an extra hour.

Comment: It appears to be ignoring the time zone entirely. When I run it, I get the time_t value for 11-Apr-2017 13:00 in my local time zone.

Comment: Because you're using `moment()` which parses the date into a local date/time value. For instance, when I run the code, I see it as several hours earlier, since I'm in UTC-05:00. You'll want to use `moment.utc()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/24782732/215552 for a similar issue.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan that's not the problem. If the specified time includes a zone, `moment()` will return the local time matching that specification. The problem in this case is that the format string doesn't match, so the zone is not being picked up.  A simple colon addition or removal makes the code work as written without having to call `.utc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string doesn't match the format.  In particular, "13:00 UTC+00:00" does not match "HH:mm:Z".  So the time zone is being ignored entirely. If you are getting UTC+1:00, it's because that's where you are. I get UTC-4:00.

If you remove the `:` between `mm` and `Z`, or alternatively, add one between `00` and `UTC`, it will work:

```js
console.log(moment("11-Apr-2017 13:00 UTC+00:00", "D-MMM-YYYY HH:mm Z").format('x'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried it. but, it is not working. It is giving 1 hour extra to me.

Comment: I observed one thing. I am selecting GMT timezone and if date is selected before 26th March, 2017. then it is working fine, but, after 26th March, 2017. It is adding 1 hr extra.

Comment: If the result of the above code is 1491915600000, then that's correct: April 11 at 13:00 UTC. If you get a different date/time from that number, then whatever you're using to convert it *back* to a date/time is the problem.
Possibly relevant: current local time in much of the what is normally the UTC time zone is not actually UTC, because they're on summer time.

Comment: It is giving me 1491915600000 only. I need to check in detail.

Comment: That's the correct answer. And you're getting it because you're asking for the `x` format, which is milliseconds since 1-Jan-1970 at midnight GMT.

Comment: It was some different issue.It was working fine at UI end. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Moment counts your timezone, to get the time without timezone offset (that is, without getting 1 hour added to your time) you can use either of the following

```
moment.utc(new Date(<date>)).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

OR

```
moment(new Date(<date>)).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```