# How to parse MomentJs date time from 2 integers?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Im trying to parse date and time for like 2 hours and i cant do it. I have 2 input integers, one is date other is time. Date is in format DDMMYY and time is in format HHSSMM. They are in utc.

```
// This is UTC time!!!!!
var date = 170218; // DDMMYY
var time = 144438; // HHMMSS
```

I want to get javascript date object that has all its UTC parameters set by momentjs. I tried the following:

```
var parse = date + "-" + time; // 170218-144438
var momentDate = moment.utc(parse, "DDMMYY-HHMMSS");
var datetime = momentDate.toDate(); // I want this to print local timezone
```

This is not working, i also tried just the date or just the time with no luck...

So how to do it?

Comment: I haven't used moment.js, but according to the website it should be `YYYYMMDD`

Comment: Yes but my incoming data is in DDMMYY format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment JS - parse UTC and convert to Local and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782732/moment-js-parse-utc-and-convert-to-local-and-vice-versa)

Comment: You might need to reformat it from that to `YYYYMMDD`

Comment: @Andreas i know how to parse utc i just dont know how to parse DDMMYY and HHMMSS

Comment: 1. What does _"This is not working"_ mean? 2. Check the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) on the format string. It's `mm` for minutes and `ss` for seconds. 3. With the correct format string and `.local()` it works: https://jsbin.com/biciyeg/edit?js,console

Comment: Then its my bad! I was in hurry to finish this fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [format string tokens](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) are incorrect (you're using "MM" for both month and minute, and you probably want "kk" for hours, unless your clock is zero-index.)

```js
var parse = "170218-144438";
var momentDate = moment.utc(parse, "DDMMYY-kkmmss");
console.log(momentDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: var DDMMYY = msg.payload.b.toString();
var HHMMSS = msg.payload.c.toString();

//time
var hour   = HHMMSS.substring(0, 2);
var minute = HHMMSS.substring(2, 4);
var second = HHMMSS.substring(4, 6);
//date
var day    = DDMMYY.substring(0, 2);
var month  = DDMMYY.substring(2, 4);
var year   = DDMMYY.substring(4, 6);
//datetime
var datetime = new Date();
datetime.setUTCHours(hour);
datetime.setUTCMinutes(minute);
datetime.setUTCSeconds(second);
datetime.setUTCDate(day);
datetime.setUTCMonth(month);
datetime.setUTCFullYear(year);